# SQL - How to get and sort multiple data in unique table

Tags: sql, join, request, partition, row-number

I have a query that return values ​​based on a boolean column: if the `id_crsp` includes a boolean true AND false, then it is selected.
Values ​​of `id_crsp` that have only a true or false value are not selected.

From this result, I sort the `id_crsp` which have duplicates, and select only the one with the oldest date.

Database values :

| id | idcrsp | date_false | boolean |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 01-01-2023 | true |
| 2 | 100 | 01-07-2022 | false |
| 3 | 200 | 01-06-2022 | false |
| 4 | 300 | 01-02-2023 | true |
| 5 | 300 | 01-08-2022 | false |
| 6 | 400 | 01-10-2022 | false |
| 7 | 100 | 01-01-2022 | false |
| 8 | 100 | 01-02-2022 | false |
| 9 | 100 | 01-11-2022 | true |

My actual request :

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         true_table.*, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id_crsp ORDER BY date ASC) rn     
     FROM 
         mydb AS true_table 
     INNER JOIN 
         (SELECT * 
          FROM mydb 
          WHERE requalif = TRUE) AS false_table ON true_table.idcrsp = false_table.idcrsp 
                                                AND true_table.requalif = FALSE)

WHERE rn = 1
```

This returns:

| id | idcrsp | date_false | boolean |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 100 | 01-01-2022 | false |
| 5 | 300 | 01-08-2022 | false |

I would like to enrich my request with :

- new column for my select, with the most recent date for the `idcrsp` with true boolean
- new column with the difference between this two dates in days

Return expected :

| id | idcrsp | date_false | boolean | date_true | difference_in_days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 100 | 01-01-2022 | false | 01-01-2023 | 365 |
| 5 | 300 | 01-08-2022 | false | 01-02-2023 | 180 |

01-01-2023 = idcrsp: 100, boolean: true, date: most recent

01-02-2023 = idcrsp: 300, boolean: true, date: most recent

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, postgresql...?

Answer (score 0):

For each `idcrsp` that have both boolean values, you want to bring the date of thte most recent true and false values. You can do this with aggregation, like so:

```
select idcrsp,
    max(case when not flag then date end) as date_false,
    max(case when     flag then date end) as date_true
from mydb
group by idcrsp
having min(flag) <> max(flag)
```

The `having` clause ensures that both boolean values are present in the group. Then we use conditional `max()`s to pick the relevant dates in each group.

How to compute the date difference in days highly depends on the database you are running. If you were running Postgres, from example, you would just substract the two expressions.

Comment: I think the `max` should be replace by `min` for the "date_false" column (seeing the expected results)

Answer (score 0):

Response works with MySql, but not with postgreSQL :

> ExampleExceptionFormatter: exception message was: ERROR: function
> min(boolean) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name
> and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).